# Check the AppPool status through power-shell and start that on remote machine

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

The requirement is to extract the server name one by one and check the AppPool status, if that is found to be stopped, make it running. below code is not helping out.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
$status = gc -path "D:\Servers\server.txt"|ForEach-Object (invoke-command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {Import-Module Webadministration Get-WebAppPoolState -name (gc "D:\AppPool.txt")})

if ($status.value -eq "Started") 
{
    Write-Host ("ApppPool already running")
}
else 
{
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Start-WebAppPool}
    Write-host ("AppPool has started successfully") 
}
```

Comment: It might be as simple as putting a semicolon between the two commands like this: `Import-Module Webadministration; Get-WebAppPoolState`

Comment: No James, it did not help. thanks

Comment: What is the content of `D:\AppPool.txt` ?

Comment: AppPool name against that I need to check the status and make it running.

Comment: So it contains a single line with just the pool name? eg. `MyAppPool`

Comment: yes, It has only the AppPool name (a single line).

Comment: I modified it again but some part is still not correct. below script is failing on multiple server but works locally:

Answer (score 5):

There were multiple problems with your code, I've gone through them individually so you can see what was stopping it from working correctly.

The syntax for `foreach` was wrong, you needed to use `{}` not `()` in this case. Normal brackets are only used like this `ForEach ($number in $numArray ) {CODE}` which you aren't.

You were checking `$status` outside the `foreach` loop - so it so was evaluating `$status` only once (with the final computers AppPool status) rather than for each computer.

Your second `Invoke-Command` didn't have a `ComputerName` parameter specified so was only running the command locally not against the remote computer, meaning the AppPool would never be started.

As you were specifying the AppPool name using `gc "D:\AppPool.txt"` this file would have to be present on *every* remote computer for it to work. I've changed this to be passed into the command as an argument so the file only needs to be on the computer running the script.

```
$Credentials = Get-Credential
$AppPools = Get-Content "D:\AppPool.txt"
$Servers = Get-Content -Path "D:\Servers\server.txt"

ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {
    ForEach ($AppPool in $AppPools) {
        $AppPoolState = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {Import-Module WebAdministration; Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $args[0] } -ArgumentList $AppPool -Credential $Credentials

        if ($AppPoolState.Value -eq "Started") 
        {
            Write-Host "$AppPool AppPool already running on $Server"
        }
        else 
        {
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {Start-WebAppPool -Name $args[0] } -ArgumentList $AppPool -Credential $Credentials
            Write-Host "$AppPool AppPool started on $Server"
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I run a non-privileged account so have to supply Credentials. If the account you're running the script as has appropriate permissions to all the remote computers you can remove the three Credentials references.

Comment: Thanks James you are awesome. There is little glitch on this updated script. It is only picking up one AppPool on multiple servers. Since I have two or more AppPool to validate and make them running how can I make that happen?

Comment: You would need to loop through the ApPools within the loop for the servers, see updated code.

Comment: This works like a charm. One minor change is to use $server instead of $_. Many thanks for your help James!

Comment: Glad I could help, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).